# Instagram: Comunity manager using his own credentials

Tags: instagram, permissions, user-accounts

I have a Business Account on Instagram.

I would like another person (like a comunity manager or so) being able to post content on my account but using his own credentials, not mine. He would be able to post content but nothing more.

Is that possible?